# Не запускается скрипт Python от суперпользователя

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pyserial

Использую Raspberry Pi 3B, Python 2.7 и библиотеку pySerial

Имеется Python скрипт `t.py`. Этот скрипт обращается к устройству через UART. Если запустить скрипт следующей командой `python t.py`, то раз в 5 секунд устройство будет моргать ламночкой. Т.е. всё отлично и сеанс связи проходит успешно.

Но если я пытаюсь запустить скрипт от суперпользователя `sudo python t.py`, то вылезет ошибка импорта библиотеки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/t.py", line 1, in <module>
import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

Подскажите, как устранить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если перевести эту строчку: `ImportError: No module named serial` то получиться
Ошибка, нету модуля с названием `serial`
Значит у вас не скачан модуль который используется в скрипте,
для того чтобы его скачать напишите `pip install serial` в командной строке
Если же не получиться то напишите таких 2 команди в CMD поочерёдно

```
sudo pip uninstall serial
Ждём окончание загрузки

sudo pip install serial
```

Подсмотрел [тут](https://overcoder.net/q/370679/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-pip-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Только мне сначала пришлось удалить сборку, а затем установить её снова командой ```sudo python -m pip install pyserial```